# Visual Studio Debug in only one thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

I use VS2017 to debug my C++ app. However, when I utilize *single-step debug*, it will switch to some thread automatically and I only want to debug one specific thread. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Stepping shouldn't change to another thread. Perhaps you have a breakpoint that the other thread is hitting.

Comment: It shouldn't switch threads, but you can always select the thread of interest in the "Thread" dropdown on the debug toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

**Breakpoints**

You can configure VS2017 debugger to filter only a specific thread. Follow [this msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/10/09/filter-breakpoints/) blog to apply one to a breakpoint. You want to filter on **ThreadId**.

---

**Thread Window**

Another way is through the [Threads Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx). Here you can view all active threads in the application.

1. Debug > Windows > Threads
2. Right click desired thread
3. Click *switch to thread*

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this extension tool:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mayerwin.DebugSingleThread

Actually other members also post this feature request and shared some suggestions with comments here:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/8543248-make-the-debugger-stick-to-the-current-thread-inst

If possible, you could view it, but if all suggestions or workaround are not what you want to get, you could also vote and add your comment for above feature requests.